# Loading custom xml or json data as pojos

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, pojo

I have few objects that I want to create in Java app by loading them from json( any text file ) to java application. The reason I want to load them is maintainability. I need a way to read them like configurations easily during startup.

I tried loading them as config but not sure if this is correct

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I understand the need for code. I will try to gather something ( newbie so going to be difficult). But I am fine with conceptual answers or discussions in plain English that I can implement or I can follow.

Comment: You can create a '@Component' class  (for example DataLoader) including a method to load the data. Annotate the method with '@PostConstruct' and the method will be called automaticaly when you run the application.